# TypeError: this.mRef.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Back again with a new type error. Working on authentication right now. Working with AngularJS and firebase. Right now when I run my function on click of the submit button I get this in my console "TypeError: this.mRef.auth is not a function". I'm thinking it's something simple but here is my login controller:

```
.controller('Login', ['$scope', 'angularFire',
    function($scope, angularFire) {

        $scope.signin = function(){
            var ref = "https://myappurl.firebaseio.com";
            var auth = new FirebaseAuthClient(ref, function(error, user) {
                if (user) {
                // user authenticated with Firebase
                console.log(user);
            } else if (error) {
                 // an error occurred authenticating the user
                 console.log(error);
                } else {
                // user is logged out
                console.log("hello");
            }
        });
            console.log($scope);
            var user = $scope.cred.user;
            var pass = $scope.cred.password;

            auth.login('password', {
                email: user,
                password: pass,
                rememberMe: false
            });
        }
}])
```

Next is the html. I have it inside a controller called login and here is what is in it:

```
<div class="inner loginbox" ng-controler="Login"
     <fieldset>
            <label class ="white">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="cred.user">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
            <label class ="white">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="cred.password">
            <div class="centerit rem-me">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <div class="white">Remember me?
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cred.remember">
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer1">
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-inverse btn-large btn-width" id="signupsubmit" ng-click="signin()">Sign in</a>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The type error I get refers to firebase-auth-client.js on line 79. In chrome I have this in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Object https://kingpinapp.firebaseio.com has no method 'auth'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating the FirebaseAuthClient, you should pass an actual Firebase reference, not just the string representation of one.

Updating your code to use the following snippet should fix your problem:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://myappurl.firebaseio.com");
var auth = new FirebaseAuthClient(ref, function(error, user) {
```

Comment: Man can't believe it was that simple. Works now!